# Any one can explain JAX-WS with Spring?

Tags: spring, jax-ws

Can you Explain in brief how JAX-WS works with Spring. I Know JAX-WS is using JAXB for un/marshaling but when it comes in picture in terms of flow. For e.g. lets say there is a service called entityEmployeeService (WebService). 
1) UI makes a HTTP request for service entityEmployeeService, then what will happen technically and flow.

Note - Majorly i want to know where marshaling and unmarshaling done in the flow of request to entityEmployeeService.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some [ready-to-use classes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-servlet) to:

1. Expose your services as JAX-WS WebServices (`SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter`)
2. Create JAX-WS WebServices stubs (`JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`) to communicate to remote WebServices.

In both cases you need to to generate JAXB beans before you start using JAX-WS WebServices (unless the cases they are passed and return simple basic types). JAX-WS `javax.xml.ws.Service` is a entry point for you to look for implementation details. In two words: it creates JDK proxy, and for each interface method invocation it marshals the arguments via JAXB.

Also Spring-WS project has a [support for JAXB marshallers/unmarshallers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-jaxb) (not JAX-WS, as it is an alternative to JAX-WS), so you can have a look at it's source code.